# Binomial test in Python vs R

Tags: python, r, scipy, binomial-cdf

I am trying to re-implement a binomial test initialy developed in `R` with `Python`. However, I am not sure if I am using the right functionality.

In `R`, I get:

```
> binom.test (2, 8, 11/2364, alternative = "greater")
0.25
```

With `Python` & `SciPy`, I use

```
from scipy.stats import binom
binom.sf(2, 8, float(11)/float(2364))
5.5441613055814931e-06
```

In fact I have to do `binom.sf(2, 8, float(11)/float(2364))` to make sure the third parameter is not `0` because of int division.

Why do the values differ? Do I have to specify the moments for Scipy / `binom.sf`?
Should I use some other library?

Comment: `scipy` has `scipy.stats.binom_test`, so no need to use the survival function. To get the same results with `binom.sf` you need `binom.sf(1, 8, float(11)/float(2364))` as you want to include the probability of 2.

Comment: The 0 was an undeleted line in the draft, sorry...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I get in R:

```
> binom.test(2, 8, 11/2364, alternative = "greater")

    Exact binomial test

data:  2 and 8
number of successes = 2, number of trials = 8, p-value = 0.0005951
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.00465313
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.04638926 1.00000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                  0.25 

>
```

Note that the p-value is 0.0005951.

Compare that to the result of [`scipy.stats.binom_test`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html) (which returns just the p-value):

```
In [25]: from scipy.stats import binom_test

In [26]: binom_test(2, 8, 11/2364, alternative='greater')
Out[26]: 0.00059505960517880572
```

So that agrees with R.

To use the survival function of [`scipy.stats.binom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html), you have to adjust the first argument (as noted in a comment by Marius):

```
In [27]: from scipy.stats import binom

In [28]: binom.sf(1, 8, 11/2364)
Out[28]: 0.00059505960517880572
```

(I am using Python 3, so `11/2364` equals `0.004653130287648054`.  If you are using Python 2, be sure to write that fraction as `11.0/2364` or `float(11)/2364`.)